# Click on MKPolygonView

Tags: ios, objective-c, mkmapview

I have created severals `MKPolygonView's` on `MKMapkView`. 
Now I want to recognize when a polygon was touched on the map. Also mark that polygon with other color.

I have one solution to do this with a longpress handler. This isn't the best solution.

Is there another easy way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes use UILongPressGestureRecogniger, all gesture recognizers are easy and convenient to use.

Comment: Could you give an example how to use it with MKPolygonView ?